# Compatible syntax for getting date of today in both SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date

How can I write the following so that it works for both SQL Server and Oracle (that is, without having to comment or uncomment, depending on the environment):

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table
WHERE -- anytime today
    -- date_requested = TRUNC(SYSDATE) -- Oracle
    date_requested = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) -- SQL Server
```

I need to compare `date_requested` with today's date (without time).

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, but I also don't understand the need for it. Both databases supports stored procedures and you can easily create a stored procedure on each with it's relevant syntax and execute them the same way from any client.

Comment: I'd hope for some IFF syntax (or whatever) in the WHERE clause, so that I could execute my request on databases which I don't want to customize in whatever way, or where I simply don't have extended rights.

Comment: Not possible as both have different ways, may work using complex technique like stored procedure that first check current RDBMS

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, a workaround could be to create a view on each database that applies the proprietary syntax to apply the filter, then your generic sql statement can simply call the view. Or if you need more flexibility with the filter as @ZoharPeled has suggested, create a procedure on each database with the same name and parameters, then call this.

Comment: What API are you using to interact with the database (i.e. ODBC/ JDBC/ etc.)?  Most APIs support at least the ODBC escape sequences and the ODBC scalar functions like `{fn now()}`.  The ODBC/ JDBC/ whatever driver will then convert that into database-specific syntax-- `sysdate` in Oracle, `getDate` in SQL Server, etc.

Comment: I'm executing those statements in either SQL Server Management Studio or in Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

create a function getDate in oracle:

```
create or replace function getDate
return date is

  l_sysdate date;

begin

  select sysdate
    into l_sysdate
    from dual;

  return l_sysdate;

end;
/
```

you can use it like this : `select getdate() from dual`

Comment: There is no need for the select or the local variable. You can reduce the function body to `return sysdate;`

Answer (score 0):

Getting current Date has different implementations in these two different databases and hence you need to use those different ways in those databases. If you are looking for workarounds to look the same, then go for a similar wrapper function and use the same in both databases.